# Fulfill Liskov substitution principle

Tags: java, liskov-substitution-principle

I have two classes:

```
public class Base {
    private final int value;
    public Base(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
    public Base divide(Base that){
        return new Base(getValue() / that.getValue());
    }
}

public class Extended extends Base{
    public Extended(int value){
        super(value);
    }
    @Override public Extended divide(Base that){
        return new Extended(getValue() / that.getValue());
    }
    public Extended getMax(Extended that){
        return new Extended(Math.max(getValue(), that.getValue()));
    }
}

Base b = new Base(3);
Extended c = new Extended(4);
```

My goal is to fulfill the liskov substitution principle but both classes don't fulfill this principle yet. I think they don't because this doesn't work:

```
Extended d = c.getMax(b); //doesn't work
Extended e = c.getMax(c);
```

Would both classes fulfill the principle if I would change the parameter of `getMax` to 'Base that'?

Comment: What is `b`? What is `c`?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot those.

Answer (score 2):

The Liskov Substitution Principles states that, when extending a type, its requirements should be the same as the base or more relaxed, while its promises should be the same or more strict. The type's methods are the main thing we are interested in examining here.

We don't care about methods that don't exist in the base class, unless they break existing promises of the class, such as introducing mutability where there was none. This method does not do anything like that, so it's irrelevant:

```
public Extended getMax(Extended that){
    return new Extended(Math.max(getValue(), that.getValue()));
}
```

We really care about methods that you override. So, let's examine the one you have:

```
public Base divide(Base that) {
    return new Base(getValue() / that.getValue());
}

@Override
public Extended divide(Base that) {
    return new Extended(getValue() / that.getValue());
}
```

- The requirements of the base method is that a valid `Base` instance is passed and that its `getValue()` does not return 0.
- The requirements of the override method is that a valid `Base` instance is passed and that its `getValue()` does not return 0.
- The promise of the base method is that a valid `Base` instance is returned.
- The promise of the override method is that a valid `Base` instance is returned and that instance happens to be specifically an `Extended` instance.

So you are honoring the Liskov Substitution Principle with these classes.

The reason your snippet doesn't compile has nothing to do with the LSP:

```
Base b = new Base(3);
Extended c = new Extended(4);
Extended d = c.getMax(b); //doesn't work
Extended e = c.getMax(c);
```

There is only one `getMax` method and it takes an `Extended` instance specifically. Yet you are passing a `Base` instance to it.

Comment: Does it matter, that this doesn't work?
`Extended d = b.divide(c);` (i added b and c in my initial post)